# What is the best way to return more values with laravel from controller to a view?

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, return

I've got some trouble by passing 2 values to a view, I'm using the code below, and tried several things like passing it in a array.

My controller:

```
public function user(User $profile)
{

    $fdate = $profile->geboortedatum;
    $tdate = date('Y-m-d');
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($fdate);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($tdate);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $years = $interval->format('%y');//now do whatever you like with $years
    //dd($y);





return view('profile.profile', compact('profile'));
}
```

My view:

```
<div>
    <row>
        <div>Naam: </div>
        <div>{{$profile->name}}</div>
    </row>
    <row>
        <div>Geslacht: </div>
        <div>{{$profile->geslacht}}</div>
    </row>
    <row>
        <div>Op zoek naar: </div>
        <div>{{$profile->partnergeslacht}}</div>
    </row>
    <row>
        <div>Leeftijd: </div>
        <div>{{$years}}</div>
    </row>
</div>
```

I would like to make it possible to return the value `$years` and `compact('profile')` from the controller to my view. I tried using a array and pass both values to the view but that didn't work out well. Does someone know some better practices from passing more values at once? That might be useful for me to know in the future too.

Thanks for helping :)

Dave

Comment: what's wrong using `compact('profile','years')`?? do you get any error??

Comment: Hi @zahidhasanemon,
I just tried compact the way you decribe it, and it is working too. I didn't knew where compact was meant for until now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an associative array rather than `compact`

```
public function user(User $profile)
{
    ...
    return view('profile.profile', [
        'years' => $years,
        'profile' => $profile
    ]);
}
```

---

**Example**

You are now able to access these variables in your view like so:

```
{{ $profile }}

@foreach($years as $year)
    {{ $year }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Okay I see, so I left `compact` away, how can I access these values in the returned array via the view? I mean, the array does not have a name like most arrays have right?

Comment: `compact` is simply a PHP function which creates an associative array (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php). So you can just create an associative array yourself do do the same thing. `Blade` will map the value of the array to a varaible named as per the key (i.e. 'years' becomes `$years`)